# Why TextWatcher is not working in custom Edittext in android?

Tags: android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I am working on custom edittext but i am little stuck in one thing, i found TextWatcher is not working in custom edittext.

```
public class InputValidation extends EditText {

public InputValidation(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public InputValidation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public InputValidation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher watcher) {
    super.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherDelegator());
}

public class TextWatcherDelegator implements android.text.TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        android.util.Log.d("TextWatcher", " beforeTextChanged :: " + charSequence.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable editable) {
        android.util.Log.d("TextWatcher", " afterTextChanged :: " + editable.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

XML layout

```
<com.example.inputvalidation.InputValidation
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="Fullname"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Above this code it's not at all calling TextWatcher states, please kindly go through my code and suggest me some solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android EditText ,keyboard textWatcher problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645332/android-edittext-keyboard-textwatcher-problem)

Comment: @v1nay hey thanks, InputFilter is working properly but TextWatcher is not working in here, can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this, it's useless:

```
@Override
public void addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher watcher) {
    super.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherDelegator());
}
```

Then, add/remove the `TextWatcher` properly, for example in `onAttachedToWindow`/`onDetachedFromWindow` methods:

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
}
```

Also, `textWatcher` should be an object, so it can be instanced from the `TextWatcherDelegator` class:

```
TextWatcherDelegator textWatcher = new TextWatcherDelegator();
```

Or directly from `TextWatcher` (which is better, if there's no other usages for `TextWatcherDelegator`):

```
public TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        android.util.Log.d("TextWatcher", " beforeTextChanged :: " + charSequence.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable editable) {
        android.util.Log.d("TextWatcher", " afterTextChanged :: " + editable.toString());
    }
}
```